# Power BI(PBIX) - Parsing Layout file

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to document the Reports, Visuals and measures used in a PBIX file. I have a PBIX file(containing some visuals and pointing to Tabular Model in Live Mode), I then exported it as a PBIT, renamed to zip. Now in this zip file we have a folder called Report, within that we have a file called Layout. The layout file looks like a JSON file but when I try to read it via python,

```
import json
  
# Opening JSON file
f = open("C://Layout",)
  
# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
#f1 = str.replace("\'", "\"")
data = json.load(f)
```

I get below issue,

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Renaming it to Layout.json doesn't help either and gives the same issue. Is there a easy way or a parser to specifically parse this Layout file and get below information out of it

```
Report Name | Visual Name | Column or Measure Name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you have come across an answer for your question yet, but I have been looking into something similar.

Here is what I have had to do in order to get the file to parse correctly.
Big items here to not is the encoding and all the whitespace replacements.

data will then contain the parsed object.

```
with open('path/to/Layout', 'r', encoding="cp1252") as json_file:
        data_str = json_file.read().replace(chr(0), "").replace(chr(28), "").replace(chr(29), "").replace(chr(25), "")
    data = json.loads(data_str)
```

Comment: I don't know why no one else has upvoted this answer, but this worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This script may help: https://github.com/grenzi/powerbi-model-utilization

a portion of the script is:

```
def get_layout_from_pbix(pbixpath):
    """
    get_layout_from_pbix loads a pbix file, grabs the layout from it, and returns json
    :parameter pbixpath: file to read
    :return: json goodness
    """
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(pbixpath, 'r')
    bytes_read = archive.read('Report/Layout')
    s = bytes_read.decode('utf-16-le')
    json_obj = json.loads(s, object_hook=parse_pbix_embedded_json)
    return json_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue.

my work around was to save it as `Layout.txt` with utf-8 encoding, then continued as you have